# AngularJS service function with timeout - return

Tags: angularjs

I have this service function in my AngularJS application and I will return log from this function.
I invoke this function with this statement:

```
vm.log = uploadService.uploadFiles(vm.files, 'Username');
```

but vm.log is always an empty string. My question now would be how I have to change the function **uploadFiles** in order to get the log statements at invokation.

```
function uploadFiles(files, username) {
        var log = '';
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              if (!file.$error) {
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                    data: {
                      username: username,
                      file: file  
                    }
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        log = 'file: ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(resp.data) + '\n' + log;
                        return log;
                    });
                }, null, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name + '\n' + log;
                });
              }
            }
        }
        return log; // this does return an empty string in every case
    };
```

Comment: Why you have $timeout while returning log object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function uploadFiles(files, username) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              if (!file.$error) {
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                    data: {
                      username: username,
                      file: file  
                    }
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    return 'file: ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(resp.data) + '\n';
                }, null, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    return 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name + '\n';
                });
              }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

your `uploadFiles` function is triggering multiple, **async**, uploads. Each call to `Upload.upload()` is async. So I'm not realy sure why you would expect calling the `uploadFiles` method to return a single string ?

One aproach to handle this would be to pass in callbacks for success and progress logging:

```
function uploadFiles(files, username, successCallback, progressCallback) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (!file.$error) {
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                    data: {
                        username: username,
                        file: file  
                    }
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    var log =  'file: ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(resp.data);
                    if (successCallback) {
                        successCallback(log);
                    }

                }, null, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    var log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name;

                     if (progressCallback) {
                        progressCallback(log);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now we can call this code by doing:

```
uploadService.uploadFiles(vm.files, 'Username', console.log, console.log);
```

If you do not want each callback to be triggered seperatly, but you would want to log a single string message, concatenated by all the different uploads, you can use:

```
function handleUploadCompleted(amountOfFilesHandled, amountOfFiles, callback, log) {
    if(amountOfFilesHandled === amountOfFiles) {
        // Finished
        if (callback) {
            callback(log);
        }
    }
}

function uploadFiles(files, username, callback) {
    var log = '';

    if (files && files.length) {
        var amountOfFiles = files.length;
        var amountOfFilesHandled = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (!file.$error) {
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                    data: {
                        username: username,
                        file: file  
                    }
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    log =  'file: ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(resp.data) + '\n' + log;
                    amountOfFilesHandled++:

                    handleUploadCompleted(amountOfFilesHandled, amountOfFiles, callback, log);

                }, function() {
                    // TODO: add logging when something went wrong ?
                    amountOfFilesHandled++:

                    handleUploadCompleted(amountOfFilesHandled, amountOfFiles, callback, log);
                }, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name + '\n' + log;
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And now we can call this using:

`uploadService.uploadFiles(vm.files, 'Username', console.log);`

Comment: If you want,  you can also use promises, but I decided to keep things simple as I don't think you are very familiar with promises.